# JavaScript Function vs Method Results

Tags: javascript

I have a function and a method that both check to see if a string is a palindrome.  When the function runs it prints out the string after each check but the method does not.  Why is this?

```
var palindromeFunctionTest = function (str) {
    if (str.length <= 1) {
        return true;
    }

    if (str.charAt(0) != str.charAt(str.length - 1)) {
    return false;
    }

    console.log('string: ' + str);


    return palindromeFunctionTest(str.substr(1, str.length - 2));
}

var palindromeMethodTest = {
    chkForPalindrome: function (str) {
        if (str.length <= 1) {
            return true;
        }

    if (str.charAt(0) !== str.charAt(str.length - 1)) {
        return false;
    }

    console.log('string: ' + str);

    return this.chkForPalindrome(str.charAt(1, str.length - 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: for completeness, you should include the way you call both of these

Comment: The code's different. You're calling `charAt()` in the second version, vs. `substr()` (correctly) in the first.

Comment: Off-topic: it looks like the most unefficient way to check for a string to be a palindrome.

Comment: as Paul Roub said you have a mistake on method, using **charAt()** instead of **substr()**, anyway I'd like to say that even I love recursion because is very beutiful, in your case is making it slower because you must use a substr, it would be much faster just using a for and charAt

Comment: Just trying to get a grasp on the differences in functions and methods so I was just using this as a test, bad oversight on my part, they both behave the same way now, thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, called them:

console.log('Is palindrome (function): ' + palindromeFunctionTest('abcdefghijkkjihgfedcba'));

    console.log('Is palindrome (method): ' + palindromeMethodTest.chkForPalindrome('abcdefghijkkjihgfedcba'));